# How to get the uuid for ble device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I am new to android development. I am working with `ble scanning`,`connection` etc.I want to display specific ble device according to `UUID`. **How can I scan ble device using UUID**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `startScan (List<ScanFilter> filters, ScanSettings settings, ScanCallback callback)` method inside class BluetoothLeScanner. Set the service UUID in the ScanFilter to display specific BLE devices according to UUIDs.

Example on scan:

```
@Override
public void startScan(final BleDeviceScanCallback callback) {
    mCallback = callback;

    List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
    if (mServiceUuids != null && mServiceUuids.length > 0) {
        for (UUID uuid : mServiceUuids) {
            ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(
                    new ParcelUuid(uuid)).build();
            filters.add(filter);
        }
    }
    ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().build();

    mBleScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
    if (mBleScanner != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mBleScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
        } else {
            // Unless required permissions were acquired, scan does not start.
            if (BleUtils.isBLEPermission(mContext)) {
                mBleScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Refer more [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=DeviceConnect-Android-master/dConnectDevicePlugin/dConnectDeviceHeartRate/app/src/main/java/org/deviceconnect/android/deviceplugin/heartrate/ble/adapter/NewBleDeviceAdapterImpl.java)

More API details can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html).

Learn about `Scan Filters` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanFilter.html).

Google Bluetooth LE Central Application Example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).

**Please Note:** `BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan` method was deprecated in API level 21. use startScan(List, ScanSettings, ScanCallback) instead.

Comment: I don't know to use scanfilter.please give me some more details about it.

Comment: I don't know how to use scanfilter.please give me some more details about it.If possible give me some example.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check if this is helpful for you.